# How to Register a Type in ServiceStack without using Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

It is possible to register a type in ServiceStack Container using a object instance and its Type?

```
 object type_to_be_registered;
 Type type = type_to_be_registered.GetType();
```

The "type_to_be_registered" implements some interfaces and I want to register the "type_to_be_registered" for its interfaces. I can get the interfaces using the following code:

```
Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
```

But how can I register the object for each of its implemented interfaces, since I do not know (at compiling time) the type of the "type_to_be_registered" object and its interfaces??

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It seems to be dead easy, you will need to describe your problem apart from the fact that you did not type the code into Visual Studio IDE it yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [docs for IOC in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#autowire-registration). Here are some examples that registers using a runtime type:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType),typeof(IMyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredTypes(typeof(MyType),typeof(MyType2),typeof(MyType3));
```

You can just register the instance as a Singleton with:

```
container.Register(instance);
```

As well as use the `CreateInstance()` extension method to create an instance from a type:

```
container.Register(type.CreateInstance());
```

If you want to register the instance of a different type, you can use reflection to call the generic method, e.g:

```
public static class ContainerExtensions
{
    public static Container Register(this Container container, 
        object instance, Type asType)
    {
        var mi = container.GetType()
            .GetMethods()
            .First(x => x.Name == "Register" 
                     && x.GetParameters().Length == 1 
                     && x.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            .MakeGenericMethod(asType);

        mi.Invoke(container, new[] { instance });
        return container;
    }
}
```

Then you can register it with:

```
container.Register(instance, type(AlternateType));
```

Comment: I do not want the type to be auto wired, I want to register a instance.

Comment: @nohros It's not clear what exactly you want so I've added a few more examples.

Comment: What I wanna do is something similar to the last code. I have an object and do not know its implemented interfaces(at compiling time), but need to register it using the interfaces returned from Type.GetInterfaces(). The only way is by creating a extension method for the Container class??

Comment: If I Register the instance using the container.Regsiter(instance) it is registered as a object and it is not resolved.

Comment: @nohros I've already provided the solution that you've asked, call the method whilst iterating over the types interfaces if you want to register it for each of them. You don't need to use an extension method, copy the impl into where-ever you want, but extension methods does make the call-site look more intuitive.